# Make for loop delayed for a certain period of time

Tags: android

In this code I want to make the for loop get delayed for 700 ms how can I achieve it. In this code the loop gets completed bez of the delay of 700 ms but I want to make each iteration of for loop delayed for 700ms.One more doubt which I should not use `Thread.sleep()` on UI thread;

```
for(int i=0;i<Uirkeys.length;i++){
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
       copyView.get(cnt1).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
       TeaxtToSpeach(map.get(Uirkeys[cnt1]));
       cnt1++;
      }
    },700);
}
```

Comment: Use AsyncTask to execute your loop. Then you can use Thread.sleep()

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code .

```
try{

 Thread.sleep(1000);
}catch(InterruptedException ex){
 //do stuff
}
```